# How to set up zoomType for Highcharts with the CodeIgniter lib

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts

I am using the CodeIgniter librairie (https://github.com/ronan-gloo/codeigniter-highcharts-library) to create Highcharts. Everything works fine but the zoom.

I am trying to setup the zoom like this :

```
$this->highcharts->set_global(array('zoomType' => 'x')) ;
```

or this

```
$this->highcharts->set_zoom_type('x');
```

But nothing would work.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used CodeIgniter Highcharts wrapper, but according to its doc (especially paragraph described here: https://github.com/ronan-gloo/codeigniter-highcharts-library#magic-methods) I'd try to use something like

```
$this->highcharts->set_chart(array('zoomType' => 'x'))
```

It should produce JSON similar to this:

```
{
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x'
    }
}
```